# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter

Tags: php, session

I have a problem with Session_start() here :

**Warning**: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\home.php:4) in **C:\xampp\htdocs\charts\home-chart.php** on line **2**

and in home-chart.php in line 2 I wrote codes like this :

```
session_start();
.
.
.
echo ' username: '.$_SESSION['user_name'];
```

---

although with this warning i can get result of `$_SESSION['user_name']` but when I try to clear this part of the code :

```
session_start();
```

I can't see any result in screen.
so, what's your solution?

```
<?php
@session_start();
require_once '../class/chart.class.php';
$chart = new chart();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='../css/home-chart.css'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='float_left' style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class='float_left' style='line-height: 9.41px; font-size: x-small;'>0<br /></div>      <div class='float_left' style="background-image: url('../image/web/chart.png'); width: 367px; height: 226px; " >
                <!-- 1 --><div class='float_left float_left column' style='margin-left:2px;'>
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(-3)); ?>
                </div>  
                <!-- 2 --><div class='float_left float_left column'>
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(-2)); ?>
                </div>  
                <!-- 3 --><div class='float_left column' >
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(-1)); ?>
                </div>  
                <!-- 4 --><div class='float_left column' >
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(0)); ?>
                </div>  
                <!-- 5 --><div class='float_left column' >
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(1)); ?>
                </div>  
                <!-- 6 --><div class='float_left column' >
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(2)); ?>
                </div>  
                <!-- 7 --><div class='float_left column' >
                    <?php echo $chart->mysql_fetch($chart->daycal(3)); ?>
                </div>  
            </div>


            <div class='float_single_full' ></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart' style="margin-left:10px;"><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(-3); ?></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart'><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(-2); ?></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart'><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(-1); ?></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart'  style='font-weight:bold'><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(0); ?></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart'><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(1); ?></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart'><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(2); ?></div>
            <div class='float_left bottom_chart'><?php echo $chart->dayofweek(3);
                    echo ' username: ' . $_SESSION['user_name'];
                    ?></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i found a question in that 100500 asked questions! i should put @ before session_start(); sorry, i'm beginner in here.

Comment: Can you please post codes from the first line? I think either spaces or newlines are there. I am 100% sure.

Comment: Nope, putting @ before session_start() just supress the warning and is not a correct way to solve the problem. Please post the all the codes in that file.

Comment: @user482594 Done! what do you think now?

Comment: it says output started at **home.php**. what for you're posting home-chart.php here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you even have blank lines before the `<?php` tag, then you can't set headers. Your start of file, with line numbers, should look like this:

```
1. <?php
2. session_start();
3. header('Cache-control: private');
```

The message says "headers sent at line 2", so you're outputting something (a space, a blank line, whatever) on line 4 of home.php

If this file is an include, you should put your `session_start();` at the top of home.php instead, and then you don't need it in this file.

Comment: no it's not include, and i try session_start(); without blank space before that, but the problem is there yet.

Comment: Post your code for home.php - the output is coming from there, and that's where the problem lies.

Comment: sorry! i mistake that was include page, and when i try to put session_start() there the warning was solved, tnx!

Comment: @Joe Thank you. Was looking out for a fix. I had blank lines before the `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you printed something before calling session_start().

You must not print anything before session_start().

The error message suggests that you first printed something in C:\xampp\htdocs\pages\home.php at line 4.

Comment: session_start() is in first line before <html> tag.

Comment: Then you must have something that forces PHP to send headers in home.php at line 4. What do you have on that line ?

Comment: that poor fella is talking of home-chart.php while output started in different file

Answer (score 3):

write this code before ***head*** tag. like below:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

session_start();
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your `php.ini file`,
2. Modifications `session.auto_start = 0` to `session.auto_start = 1`
3. Restart apache service.

Answer (score 1):

If all the above answers didn't work out for you:

Some editors, when they save a file as UTF-8, stick extra characters into the file at the very beginning (the format doesn't require it, but they do it anyway). Then refuse to show you those characters when they display the file. To see if your editor is one of these, try saving an empty file and seeing how many bytes it takes up. If it's more then zero (probably three), then you'll have to tell your editor to stop messing around (and how you do that depends on the editor).

This is not happening if you save the file as ANSI.

Answer (score 1):

Try pasting `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the top most part of your page. It will work like magic.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem and resolved the same by writting below code at top of the php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
session_cache_limiter(FALSE);
```

before

```
session_start();
```

This will surely help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a little dated, but I found that I was getting this issue when the encoding of the files is set to include BOM. When I set the encoding to UTF-8 (WITHOUT BOM), it fixed my issues.