# Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter, even though I am checking for existing session

Tags: php, session

I am having trouble with my sessions.

I get the error

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter

I have this code in 2 pages

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3*24*60*60);
  session_set_cookie_params(3*24*60*60);
  session_start();
}
```

I can only find instances of people who haven't does the isset check, so I have no idea why this is happening :(

I've checked for whitespace, my php tag is on line 1 in both files.

This is the first page, which loads dbmgmt which has the above code. I need the session code in both files because dbmgt is not always included from a page that creates a session.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3*24*60*60);
  session_set_cookie_params(3*24*60*60);
  session_start();
}
require("dbmgmt.php");
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: session\_start() \[function.session-start\]: Cannot send session cache limiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373853/warning-session-start-function-session-start-cannot-send-session-cache-lim)

Comment: Make sure that this is above any HTML code that could possibly be sent by the page.

Comment: It's definitely before any HTML or whitespace.

Comment: Can you put this code inside an isolated .php page, and *just* call this code to be sure? Are there any other errors being outputted before this one?

Comment: What is the file name and line number in the error message?

Comment: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/desnavso/public_html/Page1.php:9) in /home/desnavso/public_html/dbmgmt.php on line 5.

Comment: @Litty Ok isolating the PHP didn't throw an error. So apparently some code that is executed AFTER the session stuff, causes the session to error...

Comment: Actually, that confirms that there definitely *is* output being sent before the `session_start()`. That's where the error is generated, after all.

Comment: This is so strange. The second page is "required" immediately after the first has finished the session check, so I don't see how there can be anything sent before or between the two. I've confirmed that the second pages php is called before any HTML is loaded in the first page (tested via echoing some text). Another strange this is that this setup works on another server that I have. Could it be a server configuration thing?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call `session_start()`, which is trying to send an HTTP Header to the output of the page.

But somewhere earlier in your script, you've already started outputting the *content* of the page. The headers *must* come before the content.

Try calling this code before *any* HTML or content (**even spaces or whitespace** outside of the `?<php` and `?>` tags).

Answer (score -2):

**TRY**

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   ob_start();
?>
```

This will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks unfortunately it didn't.

Comment: With exception to a production environment, disabling error reporting will bring a *whole new slew* of issues. This is an anti-solution.